# How to avoid the screen to lock while the Windows Phone is plugged in

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Easy as that, in [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android) there's a setting called `Stay awake` that will prevent your phone to lock down while you're using it for debugging an app.

I'm looking for the same thing (could be better) for Windows Phone 8.1.

Every time I hit <kbd>F5</kbd> I need to unlock my phone or I would get the following error:

> DEP6600 : Deployment failed. Cannot deploy app when device screen is locked. Please make sure that the device screen is not locked, and try again.

or

> Error: Application launch failed. Ensure that the device screen is unlocked and device is developer unlocked. For details on developer unlock, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=195284

if I run the `AppDeployCmd` tool myself.

Is there a way I can avoid that? (without changing my lock screen time out every time of course)

Comment: Have you tried turning off the password in the lock screen settings?

Comment: that's something I wish I hadn't have to do

Comment: @PeterRitchie turning off the password does not help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this without writing a separate app. On the phone there is an option: Settings >  Lock Screen > Screen time out, which you can set to maximum available. For same phones, like lower end Nokias there is an option to set that time to never, however for newer phones such as Nokia 1320 or Nokia 1520 that maximum is only 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think it isn't possible, but here is an alternative

EDIT: You can write an separate app, wich you should run while you're developing other apps. This app must consist of this lines code.

```
DisplayRequest AppDisplayRequest = new DisplayRequest();

public MainPage()
{
     AppDisplayRequest.RequestActive();
}
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
     AppDisplayRequest.RequestRelease();
     e.Handled = true;
     Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
     Application.Current.Exit();
}
```

Comment: But this will work only when the app is running. It won't help if you stop the app - then the lock screen will engage normally. The OP asked about preventing the lock screen before deploying the app so the alternative won't help.

Comment: Yes that's right. My other idea is, that he can run this App as an extra App wich is always open, behind the real app.

Comment: That can do the trick. But you should describe it better in the answer, that OP should use the code to write a separate app which he should run if he want to avoid lock screen, then develop other apps (while the anti-lock app is running) - there is nothing like this in your answer. Please edit it. Add also that on exiting the app the *DispalyRequest* should be deacivated.

Comment: why would I want that? I need the app to stop so I can make changes and hit F5 again so the new version of app can be deployed to the device... when the device is locked it does not allow to take apps

Comment: @sebagomez The idea (as I've understood) is to write a separate app that while is running will prevent lock screen engaging. You deploy the app on the phone, close VS and forget about this code. Now when you start developing other apps, you run that anti-lock app, while it stays in the foreground it prevents lock screen, when you hit start in your new developed app it will go to foreground, while the anti-lock goes to background. Thought the code in the answer still needs many improvements, proper susped/resume, calling exit is also a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, I understand and I guess is a valid workaround. Still does not answer my question

Answer (score -1):

The resolution for the error DEP6600 should be there in the code itself instead of writing a separate app. how can this be done. in other words, the moment my app is compiled build and after deployment the error shouldn't come and the app should run even when the phone is locked