# Keeping Windows phone 8.1 screen unlocked

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am writing test automation for Windows phone 8.1. After the phone is developer unlocked (to be able to deploy apps), the maximum timeout for keeping the screen unlocked is 5 minutes. The setting is under Settings > Lock Screen > Screen times out after dropdown on the phone.

For Win phone 8.0 there is an option to never time out the screen. My question is, since this seems not to be supported yet by Microsoft, is there some way to keep the phone 8.1 screen active, without having to manually touch it?

Comment: On WP8.0 you could [unlock the screen from Simulation Dashboard](http://www.keyboardp.me/post/38976812561/get-visual-studio-to-auto-unlock-your-wp8-device-when) but it was [discontinued for WP8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632424.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid the screen to lock while the Windows Phone is plugged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936224/how-to-avoid-the-screen-to-lock-while-the-windows-phone-is-plugged-in)

Comment: Same question is answered in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936224/how-to-avoid-the-screen-to-lock-while-the-windows-phone-is-plugged-in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop an App on your device, you only have to unlocked when you run the project (F5).

Anyway, the screen can be forced to stay on using the `UserIdleDetectionMode` property of the current `PhoneApplicationService`.

To disable automatic screen lock:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

To enable it again:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
```

More information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This will work with *Silverlight* apps, for WinRT apps you will have to use [DisplayRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx).

Comment: Will this prevent from having to unlock the screen before every run (F5) ?